# how to create a curve movement of slider in unity

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I am trying to create a curved (not circular) movement of slider. Here is my demo images for reference:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have watched some tutorial but those are for circle images. I want to make this movement along the arrow images below car. Also if this can be done with just images without using slider that will be ok too. I just this done the simpler and easy way.

Comment: do you need [bezier curve](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/curves-and-splines/)

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to change the unity slider with a curve transparent image and added my own handle(car). But the movement is still horizontal.

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamali yes a bezier curve is what I am looking for

Comment: @thirteen3054 also you could make it by curve in animation

Comment: yes I did that. Now when there is a touch on car the animation is performed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I created the animation of object on the required path. And when user touches the object the animation triggers.

Comment: Don't forget to click the checkmark icon to mark this answer as "Accepted" if it solved your problem.